# VBA Hide actions during a loop

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is a dumb question, but I want to loop through a list of controls on a form and change their values.  When I do this it actually shows all of the controls changing.  This adds WAY to much time onto my execution.  Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests that you are using an unbound form. Perhaps you should consider changing to a bound form and updating the record to change the values.

You could also hide the form and only show it when your changes are complete.

Comment: Ahh I see what it is now. By Changing it the way I was I am doing an absurd amount of UPDATE statements, I did not realized that they were bound to record. If I just do one  Update of the required fields the refresh it works.  Sorry for the dumb question, this is a inherited program. Been a long day.

Comment: Always a nuisance. Do not forget that programmatic updates do not trigger most events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Application.Echo method:

```
Application.Echo False
'Do something
Application.Echo True
```

Just don't forget to add Application.Echo True to your error handler.